# jQuery Syntax Question, pretty easy I think

Tags: jquery, show-hide

$(document).ready(function() {
      $(".module .caption").hide();
      $(".module").hover(function() {
         $(this).find(".caption").slideDown(); 
       },function() {
         $(this).find(".caption").slideUp();   
       });
     });

This snippet works great for my purposes, the only caveat is that I need the .module hover function to simultaneously add a class of "under" to all other ".caption"'s that are not $this, and then remove them when the hover ends. So basically I don't want the "module" that is hovered to get the class, I want it to do exactly what I am showing here...sliding .caption up and down on end hover, I just want all other ".caption"s to get the under class when any ".module" is hovered.

Just hitting a dead end with what I have been trying, want to do it in the same function. Any ideas?

Comment: `$(".caption").not($(this)).addClass("under");` ... `$(".caption").not($(this)).removeClass("under")`;

Comment: Ben's answer is the shortest. I like it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your html structure something like this might do it:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $(".module .caption").hide();
  $(".module").hover(function() {
    $(this)
      .find(".caption").slideDown().end()
      .siblings('.module').children('.caption').addClass('under');

   },function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.find(".caption").slideUp();

    setTimeout(function() { 
      $this
        .siblings('.module').children('.caption').removeClass('under');   
   }, 1000);
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Presto. Thank you sir. And all others who offered a way. Much obliged.

Comment: Thanks and you're welcome!  I love the power that .end() provides.

Comment: One other hope, is it possible to remove the class under with a timer, this way the slide effect has a second to finish before the content drops behind? Just like 1 second should be enough.

Comment: I don't do a ton to delay things, but I think that's close.  Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the class to all other captions, and then remove it from the matched caption. At the end of the hover just remove it from all of them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function () {

        $('a').hover(function () {
            $(this).addClass('on');
            $('a:not(.on)').addClass('noton');

        }, function () {
            $(this).removeClass('on');
            $('a:not(.on)').removeClass('noton');

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this will help as i don't know what the "under" class does exactly.

```
$(".module").hover(function() {
         $(".caption").addClass("under");
         $(this).find(".caption").removeClass("under").slideDown(); 
       },function() {
         $(this).find(".caption").slideUp();
         $(".caption").removeClass("under");   
       });
```